# Iterate over a dictionary and changing the value of each item based on a condition in a loop in Ansible

Tags: loops, ansible

I have a file in host_vars folder which looks like this:

```
tags:
  tag1: value1 
  tag2: value2 
  tag3: ''  <<-- This is an empty value which I would like to fill with some string
```

Now I wanted to go through each of these items and check if the value is empty and if it is add "NA" as a string to it, I used the following code for this:

```
 - name: Clean any Tag inconsistencies
  set_fact:
    tags: "{{ item }} + NA"
  when: (item | length == 0)
  with_items: tags
 - debug: var=tags
```

However, this does not do anything, it just prints the same list when checking the debug. What is wrong with this approach?

**Edit:**

I changed my code to respect that I am using a dictionary. This is my current approach. It prints out the values with key and name but does not change any item. I also tried using the jinja default filter which did not do anything:

```
- name: "Clean Tags"
  set_fact:
    tags: "{{ (tags | default('NA', true)) }}"                               
  loop: "{{ tags | dict2items }}"
```

What I would like to achieve in the end is that it checks each dict value and if it is empty, it should add the value "NA" to it, so in the end above tags dictionary will look like this:

```
tags:
  tag1: value1 
  tag2: value2 
  tag3: 'NA'
```

Comment: Your `tags` is a dictionary, not a list. The way you are trying to use `with_items` won't work as that expects a list. The `item` variable in this case is likely `tag1`, `tag2`, and `tag3`. Also, `set_fact` used in the way you are trying to will overwrite the entire dictionary. You need a way to preserve the tags.

Comment: Seems to me like you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you want to achieve with this? Are your aware of the Jinja [`default` filter](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#default)?

Comment: I took into account the comments and updated my current approach above

Comment: Your are still not explaining what you are aiming to achieve. So what do you want to do with `tags` after you have it registered?

Comment: I added what I want to achieve in my question

Comment: Not quite. No one write a playbook to register a variable. What do you want to achieve exactly, what is the purpose of the tags variable?

Comment: I need to add tags to an EC2 instance on AWS which is performed using Cloudformation. Cloudformation does not allow "empty" tags which means if I have an empty value, then it will not let me continue operation. (and no I do not plan to simply delete the empty tag value because I have several hundreds templates which should not be changed), thus, I have templates which have empty tag values and I need to have a tags dictionary which is without any empty values ...

Comment: And so would actually 'unsetting' this dict key suits your case better?

Comment: No, unsetting is not what I am aiming for, it should still be existing, just it should be specified that the value has not been set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The play below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    my_tags:
      tag1: value1
      tag2: ''
      tag3: ''
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_tags: "{{ my_tags|combine(dict(my_empty_tags|product(['NA']))) }}"
      vars:
        my_empty_tags: "{{ my_tags|dict2items|json_query(query) }}"
        query: "[?value == ''].key"
    - debug:
        var: my_tags
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  my_tags:
    tag1: value1
    tag2: NA
    tag3: NA
```

---

The same result can be achieved without *json_query*. Replace the task vars

```yaml
      vars:
        my_empty_tags: "{{ my_tags|dict2items|
                           selectattr('value', 'eq', '')|
                           map(attribute='key')|
                           list }}"
```

---

`tags` is a playbook's keyword. You should have seen:

```sh
[WARNING]: Found variable using reserved name: tags
```

---

> Q: *"What happens in the set_fact section?"*

A: Decompose the filter. First, create the [product](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#products) of the empty tags and the string 'NA'

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ my_empty_tags|product(['NA'])|list }}"
```

gives

```
  msg:
  - - tag2
    - NA
  - - tag3
    - NA
```

Then [create dictionaries from the items in the list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-and-selecting-data)

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dict(my_empty_tags|product(['NA'])) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg:
    tag2: NA
    tag3: NA
```

The last step in the filter is to [combine](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-hashes-dictionaries) the dictionaries.

Comment: Wow, this does indeed work! It looks extremely complicated .... I thought it would be a bit easier to accomplish such a thing :( I do understand what happens in the vars section, but would you mind giving a short explanation on what happens in the set_fact section?

Comment: Sure. Three filters are needed `product, dict, and combine`. I've updated the answer. Feel free to experiment on your own.